# Наследование методов в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Хочу реализовать класс Vector как сущность линейного пространства, а затем от него наследовать обычный DoubleVector и Matrix. Для этого мне бы хотелось *определить* метод сложения 2х объектов у *родителя*, но чтобы у наследника *возвращался* объект класса *наследника*. Проблема в том, что при наследовании тип возвращаемого объекта остаётся как у объекта класса родителя, но мне хотелось бы, чтобы метод наследника сразу возвращал объект класса наследника. Пример:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    int n{0};
    A(int n) { this->n = n; }

    void operator+=(const A& other) { n += other.n; }
    A operator+(const A& other) {
        auto res = A(this->n);
        res += other;
        return res;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B(int n): A(n) {}

    void operator-=(const B& other) { n -= other.n; }
    B operator-(const B& other) {
        auto res = B(this->n);
        res -= other;
        return res;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = (B(5) + B(6)) - B(4);
    std::cout << a.n << std::endl;
}
```

Сумма двух объектов класса `B` является классом `A`, для которого операция вычитания не определена, поэтому код упадёт. Вопрос: можно ли не переписывая методы решить эту проблему?

Comment: Матрица, как *наследник* вектора? Это вектор - матрица, которая..., а не матрица - вектор, который... По-моему, решение в корне неверное.

Comment: вы запутались в понятиях класса и обьекта. Что вы хотите, я так и не понел...

Comment: Вектор суть элемент линейного пространства, для которого определены базовые операции линейной алгебры, поэтому для меня вектор первичнее матрицы.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что при наследовании оператор + будет возвращать объект класса родителя, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы он возвращал объект класса наследника

Comment: Так ведь наследование - не первично-вторично, а отношение ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ. Кто мешает вам использовать композицию или еще что? Если можно ответить на вопрос "A - это B, но такой, что..." - то о наследовании можно *думать* (это еще не 100%, что оно имеет смысл). Если этого нет - говорить о наследовании практически бессмысленно. Итак, продолжите - "Матрица - это вектор, который..."?

Comment: @Harry матрица это вектор, для которого определены дополнительно некоторые операции, такие как, например, умножение матриц.

Comment: Т.е. вы можете подставить матрицу вместо вектора, и все будет работать?

Comment: Да, но я хочу другой архитектуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте надо просто вынести оператор -, сделав его свободным, а не привязывать жестко к классу, и конструктор для приведения типов:

```
class A {
public:
    int n{0};
    A(int n) { this->n = n; }

    void operator+=(const A& other) { n += other.n; }
    A operator+(const A& other) {
        auto res = A(this->n);
        res += other;
        return res;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B(int n): A(n) {}
    B(const A& a):A(a){}

    void operator-=(const B& other) { n -= other.n; }
};


B operator-(const B& that, const B& other) {
    auto res = B(that.n);
    res -= other;
    return res;
}


int main() {
    auto a = (B(5) + B(6)) - B(4);
    std::cout << a.n << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Но получается, что если бы у меня, допустим, в классе `A` лежал массив, то он бы сначала скопировался в приведении типов, а затем уже я его ещё раз копировал в `res = B(that)`?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вызывается оператор у класса родителя изменяются только данные этого родителя. У наследника личные данные (*которые определены в классе B*) не меняются. Класс родитель ничего не знает о других наследниках, по этому возвращает себя.

Чтобы наследник возвращал себя нужно всё-таки переопределить метод. Вот так:

```
class B: public A {
public:
    B(int n): A(n) {}

    void operator-=(const B& other) { n -= other.n; }
    B operator-(const B& other) {
        auto res = B(this->n);
        res -= other;
        return res;
    }
    B operator+(const A& other) {

      // здесь работает метод родительский
      A::operator+=(other);

      // возвращаем себя (наследника)
      return  *this; }
};
```

Comment: Так мы скорее переопределяем оператор +=, но для оператора + придётся писать тот же код, что и был.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что хотя и класс `B` имеет оператор `+`, но он возвращает обьект типа `А`, а этот тип не имеет ни `operator-(B)`, ни  оператор преобразования в `В`, для того, чтобы выполнить  `(B(5) + B(6)) - B(4)`. Чтобы это было возможно,  оператор, определенный в базовом классе, нужно выполнить последным:

```
A a = B(5) + (B(6) - B(4))
```

Или же оператор базового класса должен возвращать другой тип, который может неявно преобразоваться в `В`( вариантов можно предложить много). Вот пример на основе написанной вами:

```
class A {   
public:
    int n{ 0 };
    A(int n) : n(n) { }
    //возвращайте содержащийся обьект(или ссыльку)  
    int operator+=(const A& other)
    { 
        n += other.n; 
        return n;
    }
    int operator+(const A& other) {
        A a = *this += other;       
        return a.n;
    }   
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int n) : A(n) {}
    B operator-=(const B& other)
    {
        n -= other.n;
        return *this;
    }
    // лучше оператор определить как не член класса
    //она ничего не делает с данным обьектом
    B operator-(const B& other) {               
       B b = *this -= other;      
       return b;
    }
    operator int() { return n; }
};


int main()
{   
    B b = (B(5) + B(6)) - B(4); 
    A& a = b;
    std::cout << a.n << std::endl;  
    return exec();
}
```

P.S. Базовый класс никак не нужен пользователью наследника, поэтому тут уместнее закрытое(защищенное) наследование

Comment: Я использовал int для краткости записи, так-то там массив, а для него приём преобразования в int не прокатит. А в целом проблему я понимаю (и скобки были специально поставлены).

Comment: повторюсь, вариантов много, и  важно, чтобы операция базового класса возвращала тип, который  может неявно преобразоваться в  тип наследника, чтобы выполнить приведенный вами цепочку операций.  Вот и решайте как сделать.  Я бы вообше не пользовалься наследованием.

Comment: решение Harry в этом и состоит.